# PHP system() command doesn't to work on localhost

Tags: php, batch-file, locking, cmd

I have this code:

```
<?php
system('shutdown -s');
?>
```

It works just fine, shuts down my localhost and everything. But this doesn't lock the computer:

```
<?php    
system('Rundll32.exe System32\User32.dll,LockWorkStation');
?>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Sorry, the code wasn't formatted correctly the first time for some reason.

Comment: Did you try your second command in a simple DOS prompt? (outside of PHP)

Comment: @Jocelyn that is a valid a command on windows.

Comment: @David that wasn't my question.

Comment: @Jocelyn I thought that was -possibly- your issue with it. 
I tried it locally with PHP and it worked fine. Does the command work for you without php?

Comment: The command works perfect in a batch file, command prompt, etc. I need to know why it won't work in the php script.

Comment: Does it work better using the full path to Rundll32.exe? On my computer it is "C:\WINNT\system32\Rundll32.exe", you'll have to check what is the correct path on your computer. Also maybe with forward slashes instead of backslashes...

Comment: You may also try replacing system() with [exec()](http://php.net/exec)

Comment: I've tried the full path, that doesn't work. I think I tried exec(), but I can't remember, I've tried so many things haha. I'll try exec again.

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine on my computer (locks the current session).

Comment: Does it work with the full path to User32.dll?

Comment: Are you running this under a webserver? A webserver won't generally have access to the console and can't do things like locking the screen.

Comment: @Pekka: already answered, read previous comments.

Comment: @Jocelyn not in any comment that I can see. Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server isn't running in the user session, and so has no ability to lock it.

Comment: Because the system can be shut down by anything with appropriate privileges; doing so doesn't require a user session.

Comment: Okay, do you have any other suggestions on how I could lock the computer?

Comment: Run a user daemon that performs the lock instead, and communicate with it using mailslots or the like.